# Error in knearest(Darr, P_set, K) : object 'knD' not found

Tags: r

i used Package ‘smotefamily’ in R 
then i used example in the CRDN doc

```
data_example = sample_generator(10000,ratio = 0.80)
genData = ADAS(data_example[,-3],data_example[,3])
genData_2 = ADAS(data_example[,-3],data_example[,3],K=7)
```

but there have a error

```
Error in knearest(Darr, P_set, C) : object 'knD' not found
```

I just want to use ADAS .
this is the document link:
[document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smotefamily/smotefamily.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracing this error, it's thrown from `knearest` whose source is:

```
> knearest
function (D, P, n_clust) 
{
    if (requireNamespace("FNN", quietly = TRUE)) {
        knD <- FNN::knnx.index(D, P, k = (n_clust + 1), algo = "kd_tree")
    }
    knD = knD * (knD != row(knD))
    que = which(knD[, 1] > 0)
    for (i in que) {
        knD[i, which(knD[i, ] == 0)] = knD[i, 1]
        knD[i, 1] = 0
    }
    return(knD[, 2:(n_clust + 1)])
}
```

The `if` statement in this function has no `else` for when `requireNamespace` returns `FALSE` and the `FNN` dependency is only in 'Suggests' in the package metadata so isn't automatically installed. To get the example to run first install `FNN`:

```
install.packages("FNN")
```